# how disable ctrl + enter shortcut in gmail new compose?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible disable ctrl + enter shortcut in gmail new compose ?

[image]

Comment: run a script in the console and disable this - is this what you want?

Comment: yes, i can embed jquery to gmail page, run its or run a script in console! but what is script to disable?

Comment: Have you checked Greasemonkey?

Comment: i can run script to page and not problem for run script in page but dont know how disable ctrl+enter shortcut, i use  event.stopPropagation() and event.preventDefault() in keydown event but not disable!